# How to invalidate the session token via ASP.NET Identity 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-identity

This [Security.StackExchange answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/71713/60628) explains why and when it is necessary to invalidate the current session token.  My question is: How do I invalidate the session token via ASP.NET Identity 2?

Here's the relevant quote from the referenced answer.  The original question asked whether, during new user sign-up, email verification (by clicking a link in an email sent to the user-supplied email address) should be followed by password-based login.

> You should invalidate the session token and generate a new one when the user goes to the first step of your signup process. This will ensure that if the session was fixated, the attacker cannot then ride the logged in session. If you want the extra security of them entering their password again, then you must refresh the session token at the first step and once the confirmation link is followed.